# How to find the list of users who had not logged in gerrit

Tags: git, github

I want to removed or find the user who had not logged in git-gerrit from past one year, I generated gerrit user from data base but how could I list the users who had not logged in gerrit from a long time. Is there any way to find user with its last login date or sometime like that.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with lastlog

```
sudo lastlog -b 365
```

To filter system users user grep

```
sudo lastlog -b 365 | grep -v 'Never log'
```

see man lastlog for additional options.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer, does this command return the user who had login to server(unix) or who had access gerrit application. I have used the below command to get the info but that does not provide last login date of user. (ssh -p 29418 gerrit-server-name gerrit query  age:1y |grep "email:"|sort|uniq  )

Comment: login to the system, not sure about gerrit.